# How to make autocompletion work with angular and ionic

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, autocomplete

I want to create a registration form with angular and ionic.

Because I'm using a library, I'd like to stick with the angular material, instead of the Ionic one.

So this is my code.

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="itemForm" novalidate>
  <mat-form-field *ngIf="loginType === 'email' && itemForm.get('email')">
    <mat-label>{{ 'EMAIL' | translate }}</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="email" type="email" autocomplete="email" inputmode="email" />
    <mat-icon matSuffix>mail</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button
    color="primary"
    mat-raised-button
    [disabled]="itemForm?.invalid || !isPasswordValid"
    type="submit"
    class="submit-button"
    aria-label="Save"
    (click)="onSubmit()"
  >
    {{ 'LOGIN' | translate }}
  </button>
</form>
```

But when I'm clicking in the e-mail field, the autocompletion isn't working, meaning Google isn't proposing me the autocompletion that I'll have on an normal Chrom browser

Does somebody see the error ?

The same piece of code is actually working on a website. So I'm pretty confused.

Comment: if you are facing any console error please add here.

Comment: "But when I'm clicking in the e-mail field, the autocompletion isn't working." What do you mean by that? What did you expect to happen? And how does this "not working" manifest?

Comment: @Storytellerr I sadly do not face any errors